# Do I always need to set PYTHONPATH to my project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment

I was having trouble to import modules of own project to other files of the project. I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
my-project/

|-main.py
|-test/
  |__init__.py
  |-test_service_class.py
|-services/
  |__init__.py
  |-service_class.py
```

I wanted to import `service_class.py` to `test_service_class.py`, so I coded:

```py
from services import service_class
```

Then I got an error saying that services is not a module... I searched a lot about it and got two ways to fix this error.

The first was adding the following weird code on the top of the files, witch looks really wrong, but works:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('<path_to_module>')
```

And the other was adding my Project's path to my `PYTHONPATH`...

I'm actually using the `PYTHONPATH` option, that looks more "correct", still I think it's weird because for each Project I start, I'll have to include the path to `PYTHONPATH`...

**So I wanted to know if is it the best way to fix this problem, if aren't there better options, because I never had to set my Project's directory on `PYTHONPATH` before.**

Thank you, I'm looking forward for answers!

Comment: Usually your current working directory will be the first directory in the PYTHONPATH. Make sure to `cd` into `my-project` first and run code from there.

Comment: Also depends how invoke the test, might need python -m pytest

Comment: Hm... I was running the project using its root directory, I'll try doing it again with a project that I didn't add to `PYTHONPAYH`.
And also, I don't think it's related to pytest, because it's running without flaws after I added to `PYTHONPAYH`.